# STA timing closure for asynchronous FIFO

Tags: fpga, timing-analysis, fifo, asynchronous

I have implemented an [asynchronous FIFO](https://github.com/buttercutter/afifo/blob/master/async_fifo.v)

However, I have setup timing violation when *read_clk* is having phase shift of 270 degrees , and *write_clk* is having phase shift of 90 degrees.

Both *read_clk* and *write_clk* are having the same clock frequency.

Could anyone advise ?

Please see below the reports from Vivado tool:

[image: timing]

[image: schematics]

[image: report_cdc]

Comment: Why a do you use phase shift? Why a fifo?

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider that your clock is a 100 MHz one. The period is 10 ns.

Read clock has a phase shift of 270 degrees which corresponds to 7.5 ns.

Write clock has a phase shift of 90 degrees which corresponds to 2.5 ns.

The time difference between your two clocks is 5 ns. It is 200 MHz.

So depending on the clock frequency and shift, the constraint can be stronger (200 MHz) in my example

Comment: I had added some Vivado reports outputs in my original question.  Someone told me to use `set_max_delay` , but I am not sure how and which path to use it on.   Should I use `set_max_delay` between read_pointer and write_pointer ?

Comment: Are your two clocks coming from the same oscillator? If it is not the case, yes you should put a set max delay